# Program for splitting whitespace strings won't work

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

I'm trying to make a program for splitting whitespaced strings in a vector, but it doesn't delete the 2nd part of the original string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

#include<sstream>
#include<fstream>
#include<list>
#include<numeric>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    vector<string> words;

    words.push_back("aa bb");
   string& e=words[0];
    string::iterator it=find(e.begin(),e.end(),' ');
    if(it!=e.end()){
        words.push_back(e);
        e.erase(it,e.end());
        string& e2=words.back();
        it=find(e2.begin(),e2.end(),' ');;
        e2.erase(e2.begin(),it+1);
    }
    for(auto& f:words)
        cout<<f<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: @ohndoeisabro After this statement  words.push_back(e); the reference e can be invalid.

Comment: FYI, [std::istringstream](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a973c022c5bb83a8) does all of this work for you.

Comment: @nonock If you use version-specific `c++??` tags, please use them *in addition* to the main `c++` tag (for better question visiblity). Also, I don't see anything C++14-specific here, not sure why you thought that tag would fit better.

Comment: auto&  on C++14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your code is correct, but the code failed to complete the task because you ***used a reference to element of a vector whose capacity changed***.

```
string &e = words[0];
...
words.push_back(...);
...
```

[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is typically implemented to store data by requesting contiguous blocks of memory. When the current capacity is used up *(as a result of inserting more elements)*:

1. new contiguous memory block with a bigger capacity is created.
2. elements from the old block are ***copied*** to this new block.
3. old memory block is destroyed.
4. references, pointers and even iterators of objects stored in the old memory block become invalid.

If you know the total number of items to be stored in a vector, you can [set the capacity of the vector in advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid invalidation:

```
std::vector<string> words;
words.reserve(3);
words.push_back("aa bb");
string &e = words[0];
...
words.push_back(...);
...
```

[std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) unlike `std::vector` is implemented as a *linked-list*. Although it does not support random element access *(very disappointing)*; it does not require contiguous memory blocks and never poses risk of invalidation unless you explicitly destroy a referenced element.

***conclusion***:

Information about the total number of elements to be stored in `std::vector` may not be readily available, thus `std::list` seem to be more reliable in situations where references to elements of rapidly expanding containers are needed. I recommend use of `std::list` for this task.

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::list<string> words;
  words.push_back("aa bb");

  string &e = words.back();
  string::iterator a = e.begin(), b;

  while (1)
  {
    b = std::find_if(a, e.end(), [](auto &c){ return (c == ' '); });
    words.push_back(string(a, b));
    a = std::find_if_not(b, e.end(), [](auto &c){ return (c == ' '); });
    if (a == e.end()) break;
  }

  for(auto &f: words) cout << f << endl;
  return 0;
}
```